# Using Javascript/JQuery Back_End data transfer from one html to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(Using only Javascript or JQuery) Back_End

Below I have three snippets of html  code that are on one html page. When the form elements have been selected, the submit button should send the values of the form to another html page and display the elements inside a table. The process should be back_end and not re-direct to the second page. I need to use Javascript or JQuery. (No Ajax)

1st html page

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
    <option value="60">6</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <label>Choose Your Pickup Date:</label>
  <input id="date" type="date">
</form>
<form>
  <label>Additional Requests or Comments:</label>
</form>
<input TYPE="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-round-lg btn-lg getStarted">
```

2nd html page

```html
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why all the form tags? And why no Ajax? And what is the backend? And why even use a backend, You can just update some innerHTML

Comment: This is just plain HTML, where's your js? (You did try something before asking, right?)

Comment: how about using `localStorage` for this purpose? .

Comment: If you have ONE form you do not need ANY JS if you go to a backend

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe I'm missing something, but how can this be done (Manipulate the DOM) without JS?

Comment: I need to use JS to manipulate the DOM

Comment: How would I updated using innerHTML?

Comment: First time using stackoverflow

Comment: @AlonEitan if he is going to a backend he does not need ANY JS if he has one form instead of 3

Comment: Oh, got it @mplungjan - I just was confused because this question isn't tagged under any backend related tags

Answer (score 1):

Using innerHTML. NOTE: This will NOT update an HTML file on the server.

I strongly suggest if you have to send to the server and NOT want to use AJAX, then just submit ONE form without any JS (except perhaps for validation) and have the backend fill the HTML and return it

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    var res = document.getElementById("result");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML=document.getElementById("num").value;
    td2.innerHTML=document.getElementById("date").value;
    td3.innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").value;
    
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    res.appendChild(tr);
    return false; // cancel submit
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <select id="num">
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
    <option value="60">6</option>
  </select>
<br/>
<label>Choose Your Pickup Date:</label>
  <input id="date" type="date"><br/>
  <label>Additional Requests or Comments:</label><br/><textarea id="text"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-round-lg btn-lg getStarted">
</form>

<table>
<tbody id="result"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works on one html page; however, it does not work if I want to simply display the form elements on a different page.

Comment: What do you mean “on another page” you have not clearly explained what the aim of this is.

Comment: I have one html page with the form. When the form is submitted, I want to know if there is a way to display the form elements on another html page. I tried the above snippet; however, it does not work.

Comment: What does “does not work” mean? And you still have not told us what you have on the back end